# Calculating the exponent of two BigIntegers in Java (implementing Socialist Millionaire)

Tags: java, cryptography, biginteger

I'm attempting to port a Python file to Java, but I'm having some troubles(could be caused my my limited knowledge of Python). The python file is an example of implementing the Socialist Millionaire problem. I'm having some issues with how Java handles BitInteger operations.

Python:

```
def step1(self):
    self.x2 = createRandomExponent()
    self.x3 = createRandomExponent()

    self.g2 = pow(self.gen, self.x2, self.mod)
    self.g3 = pow(self.gen, self.x3, self.mod)

    (c1, d1) = self.createLogProof('1', self.x2)
    (c2, d2) = self.createLogProof('2', self.x3)

    # Send g2a, g3a, c1, d1, c2, d2
    return packList(self.g2, self.g3, c1, d1, c2, d2)
```

Java:

```
public BigInteger[] step1() {
    x2 = getRandomExponent();
    x3 = getRandomExponent();

    g2 = new BigInteger(gen + "").pow(x2.intValue()).pow(mod.intValue());
    g3 = new BigInteger(gen + "").pow(x3.intValue()).pow(mod.intValue());

    BigInteger[] logProof1 = createLogProof("1", g2);
    BigInteger[] logProof2 = createLogProof("2", g3);

    BigInteger c1 = logProof1[0];
    BigInteger d1 = logProof1[1];
    BigInteger c2 = logProof2[0];
    BigInteger d2 = logProof2[1];

    return new BigInteger[] { g2, g3, c1, d1, c2, d2 };
}
```

I'm getting the following error(line 24 is where g2 is calculated):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: Negative exponent
    at java.math.BigInteger.pow(BigInteger.java:1395)
    at n/a.crypto.SMPCheck.step1(SMPCheck.java:42)
    at n/a.Testing.main(Testing.java:24)
```

Which is caused by the fact that BigInteger.intValue() is producing a negative number when called. Does anybody have a solution for calculating the exponent of two BigIntegers?

Python source: http://shanetully.com/2013/08/mitm-protection-via-the-socialist-millionaire-protocol-otr-style/

Comment: The value returned by `BigInteger.intValue()` is not purposedly negative, it's overflowing.

Comment: How large are your random exponents allowed to be?

Comment: and what is `mod` in your code?

Comment: @DavidWallace : I am using the number the python example provided. The random exponents are 1536 bits long.

Comment: You want to raise integers to exponents that are 1536 bits big?  Really?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the wrong method to compute the power, then the mod of that. The `pow` method does not accept negative exponents, and as it seems like you want also to mod that, there is a perfect method for you: `modPow`. This does an exponentiation, then a mod operation, and it accepts negative exponents.

```
public BigInteger[] step1() {
    x2 = getRandomExponent();
    x3 = getRandomExponent();

    g2 = new BigInteger(gen + "").modPow(x2, mod);
    g3 = new BigInteger(gen + "").modPow(x3, mod);

    BigInteger[] logProof1 = createLogProof("1", g2);
    BigInteger[] logProof2 = createLogProof("2", g3);

    BigInteger c1 = logProof1[0];
    BigInteger d1 = logProof1[1];
    BigInteger c2 = logProof2[0];
    BigInteger d2 = logProof2[1];

    return new BigInteger[] { g2, g3, c1, d1, c2, d2 };
}
```

Comment: 2^x where x has 1536 bits requires 2^1533 bytes of memory which is much, much more than the number of atoms in the observable universe.

Comment: Do you have a computer which has more memory than 2^1000 universes have atoms?

Comment: @PeterLawrey How is that relevant?

Comment: @PeterLawrey It seems to be irrelevant, if the answer got accepted.

Comment: @tbodt You changed the code after my comment to match my answer.  The point being why would you suggest a solution which no computer in the universe could ever perform.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Well, now thanks to the editing grace period, the original is gone forever.

Comment: This answer is bordering on incorrect.  The `modPow` method does NOT do an exponentiation then a mod, as you assert.  Also, it only accepts negative exponents in a limited set of circumstances; although that's really not the issue here.  This would be a better answer if it correctly explained WHY it is necessary to use `modPow` instead of `pow`.  Sorry, but I find Peter's answer far superior to this one.

Answer (score 5):

Using high powers and then performing a mod is very slow.  For this reason, BigInteger provides a [modPow(BigInteger, BigInteger)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#modPow%28java.math.BigInteger,%20java.math.BigInteger%29) method which appears to do what you want.